# Freelancing from India to US employer: Can they deposit pay to my US Account?

Tags: united-states, india, online-payment, payment

I recently moved back to India from USA as I didn't get H1B Visa. I have started working for same company from India as a contractor.

I still have my bank account active in USA. Can my company *legally* deposit my salary in my bank account?

I've looked at paypal but they have numerous fees going up to 5% of my salary. I want to use xoom to get money from my us bank account to India bank account.

Please advice.

Comment: If you are a _contractor_ instead of an employee, then the money you get from the company is _self-employment income_ to you, not salary. You need to talk to the company about this; there may be tax issues involved which are different for wages versus self-employment income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still have my bank account active in usa. Can my company legally
>   deposit my salary in my bank account?

Of course they can. *Where* they deposit is of no consequence (in the US, may be in India). It is *who* they deposit it for that matters. You need to file form [W8](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf) with the company, and they may end up withholding portion of that pay for IRS.

You'll need to talk to a tax adviser in India about how to report the income back at home, and you may need to talk to a tax adviser in the US about what to do if the company does indeed remit withholding from your earnings.